# Server need to be restarted when mirth is searching for a text

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mirth

I searched for a patient using his id in mirth. While filtering it i didn't select the dates. I entered the patient id and clicked search. Because of that the server itself is got stuck. Maybe due to large DB. After restarting the server i filtered for only two days. Even then server got stuck. Why its happening before that i never see this kind of error. I saw post related to this. The below link will resolve my problem.

http://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=11566

Answer (score 1):

The message browser does attempt to warn you when performing general text searches:

[image: Text search warning]

And yep, sounds like you've answered your own question... custom metadata columns will definitely help:

[image]

Comment: Echoing this, it's pretty much always a good idea to use the patient ID and full name as meta data columns, because for support you'll need this info.   Also if you are dealing with large amounts of data, you need to use a real database like postgres or MS SQL, Derby can and will get corrupted over time, and the performance is terrible.  It's fine for development, but not anywhere there is high volume.